# Problems installing over Windows 10

Tags: system-installation, microsoft-windows

Having some troubles installing Linux on my desktop computer, just wondering if anyone might be able to give me some sort of direction.

Basically had a great experience with Linux, terrible one with Windows. Have been wanting to put Linux on the desktop for awhile but held off because of program compatibility. Lately windows has been stuck in recovery loop, got sick of it, and this morning I installed linux over it. Assume that something is damaged and might need a new Harddrive but hoping not?

It isn't dual installed with Windows. A few months ago I was going to try but it looked way out of my expertise. And this morning I just didn't care enough to try save my stuff.

- I had initial problems when I clicked install. I didn't save the error but it said something like the partition was acting like it had windows on it, but it was corrupted or had a problem and I had to click okay on it. Installed all right, I could use it.

Pretty much the only windows program I use at the moment is World of Warcraft to muck around on when i'm bored, so was messing round trying to see if I could get it running first and foremost.

- I updated Wine. Noticed that when I left the computer and it idled and the screen went off, I couldn't get it back on. Restarted it.
- Installed Tweaks, too.
- I'd looked up a page of 'what to do with a fresh install' and followed a tutorial on changing graphics cards settings because, well, figured that was the next step. Reset the computer as per instruction. Battle.net client/screen thing went white, and I couldn't use it so I assumed I messed that up.
- Found a better tutorial on how to install my driver and was going back to give it a try when I got the sleep mode problem again. Restarted.
- Trouble restarting. I got a prompt from something called busybox and now I'm stuck.

And if it helps the problems I had with Windows were:

- It booted all my devices off the internet and messed with my router every 30 seconds or so. Resolved.
- Periodically just threw a fit and died.
- Problem with the sound dying after an update. Resolved.
- 100% disk usage glitch, which froze up the computer. Partially resolved.
- Start menu glitch after an update. Resolved.
- Last 6 months or so it's just been crashing and stuck in recovery loop.

Haven't kept a strict record and I know there's been some other lame glitchy things happen that I haven't remembered, mostly just new os related stuff though I think.

Haven't used it that much mainly because of the internet problem, it was an expensive paperweight for a long time. Guessing it had some malware or viruses on it or whatever on it to cause the recovery problem - would that be enough to wreck the drive?

Any help would be appreciated :). I will try to provide details for any questions asked.

Comment: Download elementary-os iso.reboot your System with the CD and First delete all your partitions.

Comment: After deleting your partitions with elementares installiert install elementary by using all free spsce on the disk. Be aware you  MUST delete all your partitions first!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a partition manager utility such a [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) (either the CD or USB version), delete all partitions on the hard drive, reboot, and then try installing it clean.
If that fails, you could also try using a utility such as [DBAN (Darik's Boot and Nuke)](https://dban.org/) - that will pretty much guarantee complete hard drive, partition, etc. erasure. 
 Kinda extreme maybe, but I've encountered drives where either the partitions wouldn't remove properly, or there was a problem with the MBR (master boot record), and DBAN solved it.

Finally, if DBAN doesn't work.  Get another hard drive / SSD.  
 If you have problems after that... well, maybe the RAM is bad.  (generally replaceable).

 If after all that you're still having problems, then more than likely you're having some other hardware failure, and maybe time to get a new system.